why I get NotImplementedError in scipopt?
I have this optimization problem:
    n=3
    z2=[1,-1,1]
    x_vars = [model.addVar(vtype="integer", name=f'x_{i}', lb=0, ub=1) for i in range(n)]
    B_vars = [model.addVar(vtype="B", name=f'B_{i}') for i in range(n)]  # Binary variables
    for i in range(n):
        permuted_z2 = z2[i:] + z2[:i]  # Generate i-th permutation of z2
        constraint_expr = sum(permuted_z2[j] * T_list[j] for j in range(n))
        model.addCons(4*x_vars[1]+2*x_vars[2]+10000*B_vars[i]<= 10000 )

    # Add constraint to ensure only one B_i is active
    model.addCons(sum(B_vars) ==1)




    # Ensure only one binary variable is active
    model.addCons(sum(B_vars) == 1)
    # Solve the model
    model.optimize()

    # Display the solution
    if model.getStatus() == "optimal":
        solution = [model.getVal(var) for var in x_vars]
        print("Optimal solution found:")
        for i, val in enumerate(solution):
            print(f'x_{i} = {val:.4f}')
    else:
        print("No optimal solution found.")

I think constraints are ok but I keep getting this error and I have no idea why:
    NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[41], line 6
          4     permuted_z2 = z2[i:] + z2[:i]  # Generate i-th permutation of z2
          5     constraint_expr = sum(permuted_z2[j] * T_list[j] for j in range(n))
          ----> 6     model.addCons(4*x[1]+2*x[2]+10000*B_vars[i]<= 10000 )
          8 # Add constraint to ensure only one B_i is active
          9 model.addCons(sum(B_vars) ==1)

    File src/pyscipopt/expr.pxi:260, in pyscipopt.scip.Expr.__radd__()

    File src/pyscipopt/expr.pxi:189, in pyscipopt.scip.Expr.__add__()

    NotImplementedError: 

I used big M method to make it linear, that's why I have 10000.

I'm not familiar with this library, but from a quick perusal online, it seems you're triggering this line in the sourcecode. Perhaps that's informative.
